# Failure resistant git pull on a lossy and flaky connection

Tags: git

We have servers deployed in buses and trains with internet dongles attached. These servers at regular intervals do a git pull to update the codebase deployed on them.
Now, due to lossy and flaky nature of internet from these dongles, git pull is frequently abandoned while in progress and that causes corruption in our local repo. We often get into a state where git starts complaining about loose git objects that very hard to heal.

It seems git pull is not very failure resistant. Just wondering if anyone has any recommendation on how we could do a git pull that is failure resistant, something like all or nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use git for this, because git transfers file-by-file (resp. diff-by-diff). You can use packages to deploy new versions of software, like .deb or .rpm or .msi depends on OS you have in buses and trains.

Packages are downloaded as one file and software is updated after whole package is downloaded and verified, so it is best way how to achieve secure update in this environment.